# django runserver can't find static files, but remote server can

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I'm writing in Pycharm, pushing to PythonAnywhere via GitHub. Django3 and Python3.7. Working through the Django Girls tutorial.

I have defined in settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

I have a template with

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "blog/css/blog.css" %}">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>DG Tutorial</title>
</head>
...
```

I have tried `python manage.py findstatic blog.css` it can't find it. I try variations of static/blog/css/blog.css and /blog/css/blog.css and get a long error message that ends with:

> django.core.exceptions.SuspiciousFileOperation: The joined path >>>(/blog.css) is located outside of the base path component (/Users/alesha/.virtualenvs/blog/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static)

So, I'm wondering why it's not looking in the STATIC_ROOT, which is located outside the base path component. Or did it? I don't know.

I then checked the django bug-tracker. Nope - it's me.

So, the wacky part is that when I port the code to PythonAnywhere, it works just as it should, blog.css gets served and happiness abounds.

I have read a millihelen of posts on this, all the django tutorial pages on staticFiles - that I'm aware of, I've quad checked for typos. I am stumpeth - coz it works! Just not on localhost.

Thank you for helping with my first ever Stack Overflow question.

[My Working Directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HN9hn.png)

[The local and the remote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/we7QT.png)

Comment: I guess you have an app called `blog`. Do you also have a `static` directory inside it, and did you put the `blog.css` file into `blog/static/blog/css`?

Comment: @Dauros I have an app called `blog` and a `static` directory and `blog.css` is in the `mysite/static/blog/css/` directory.  I'll add a picture to the OP.

Comment: Can you put the exact links that work and don't by going to inspect in the browser.

Comment: Do you have `DEBUG = True` in PythonAnywhere?

Comment: Or did you set the `staticfiles` folder setting when configuring the web app in PythonAnywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions for this problem. It's a little bit confusing at first, but `STATIC_ROOT` directory [should be empty](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#static-root). During the deployment when you run the `manage.py collectstatic` command, Django will look into each app's `static` subdirectory and will copy all the static files into `STATIC_ROOT` and the webserver will serve them from that directory (this is why it worked on PythonAnywhere). But by default the `findstatic` command *will not* look for static files in `STATIC_ROOT` directory. The quick workaround is just add `STATIC_ROOT` to [`STATICFILES_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#staticfiles-dirs) in `settings.py` then Django will look for static files in that directory as well.

But my recommendation is that you should follow the "official" way to store the static files which is inside an app's `static` subdirectory (e.g. `mysite/blog/static/blog/css/blog.css`) and keep `STATIC_ROOT` empty.

Comment: Thank you! It is a bit confusing - but makes sense from a development perspective. I kept thinking that how I was doing it would make reusability a pain - coz I'd have to go back and relocate the files back into the app directory. I was right! :D

Ah, this is why we have to run `collectstatic` whenever statics change. 

For sure - I shall follow the "official" way. Thanks, so much for the excellent explanation.

Comment: I was happy to help and welcome to SO. The reasoning behind `collectstatic` is that Python app servers are "inefficient" for serving static files and therefore the frontend web servers (e.g. Nginx or Apache) should be used for that task. And it's better to have one central location for static files (the `STATIC_ROOT` and `MEDIA_ROOT` for uploaded files), so we don't have to edit the web server's configuration each time when we add a new app to our Django project. Btw you should also relocate the `blog` app's templates files to `blog/templates`.

Comment: heh, I was thinking that this morning :) 
See you around <wave>